# Child Layout is repeating many times in ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I have a problem that I am implementing an ExpandableListView with a Grid View as a child in one parent. There are 46 images in GridView. Therefore when we open first parent it shown a grid view with more than 46 images with a slot of 46 images. Means one slot of 46 images shown then another 46 images again shown beneath that then another and then another. Means many times the same layout is repeating in one layout. I unable to find the source of the problem therefore I failed to resolve that. Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

**Code(Expandable List):**

```
public class ExpResearchListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    // Sample data set. children[i] contains the children (String[]) for
    // groups[i].
    Context context;
    /*private String[] groups = { "Research by Brand", "Research by Category",
        "Research by Price" , "Research by Fuel Economy", "Recently Viewed"};*/
    GridView label;
    TextView groupText;
    ImageView groupImg;
    ArrayList<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> groupImage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> childElement = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Integer[][] children = { 
            { R.drawable.icon_1, R.drawable.icon_2, R.drawable.icon_3, R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_5, R.drawable.icon_6, R.drawable.icon_7, R.drawable.icon_8, R.drawable.icon_9,
                R.drawable.icon_10, R.drawable.icon_11, R.drawable.icon_12, R.drawable.icon_13, R.drawable.icon_14, R.drawable.icon_15, R.drawable.icon_16, R.drawable.icon_17, R.drawable.icon_18,
                R.drawable.icon_19, R.drawable.icon_20, R.drawable.icon_21, R.drawable.icon_22, R.drawable.icon_23, R.drawable.icon_24, R.drawable.icon_25, R.drawable.icon_26, R.drawable.icon_27,
                R.drawable.icon_28, R.drawable.icon_29, R.drawable.icon_30, R.drawable.icon_31, R.drawable.icon_32, R.drawable.icon_33, R.drawable.icon_34, R.drawable.icon_35, R.drawable.icon_36,
                R.drawable.icon_37, R.drawable.icon_38, R.drawable.icon_39, R.drawable.icon_40, R.drawable.icon_41, R.drawable.icon_42, R.drawable.icon_43, R.drawable.icon_44, R.drawable.icon_45,
                R.drawable.icon_46} 
            };
    LinearLayout linear;

    public ExpResearchListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> groups, ArrayList<Integer> groupImage, ArrayList<Integer> childElement, LinearLayout linear)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.groups = groups;
        this.groupImage = groupImage;
        this.childElement = childElement;
        this.linear = linear;
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        int i = 0;
        try {
        i = children[groupPosition].length;

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return i;
    }

    public TextView getGenericView() {
        // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 64);

        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // Center the text vertically
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        //textView.setTextColor(R.color.marcyred);
        // Set the text starting position
        textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
        return textView;
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.brand_research_grid, null);
            label = (GridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gv_ResearchList_Child);
            label.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(context, children));
            label.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);
            // initialize the following variables (i've done it based on your layout
            // note: rowHeightDp is based on my grid_cell.xml, that is the height i've
            //    assigned to the items in the grid.
            final int spacingDp = 10;
            final int colWidthDp = 50;
            //final int rowHeightDp = (childElement.size()/3)*10;
            final int rowHeightDp = 107;

            // convert the dp values to pixels
            final float COL_WIDTH = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * colWidthDp;
            final float ROW_HEIGHT = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * rowHeightDp;
            final float SPACING = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * spacingDp;
            System.out.println("===================================RowHeight"+ROW_HEIGHT);
            System.out.println("===================================RowHeightDP"+rowHeightDp);


            // calculate the column and row counts based on your display
            final int colCount = (int)Math.floor((linear.getWidth() - (2 * SPACING)) / (COL_WIDTH + SPACING));
            //final int rowCount = (int)Math.ceil((childElement.size() + 0d) / 3);
            final int rowCount = 16;

            // calculate the height for the current grid
            final int GRID_HEIGHT = Math.round(rowCount * (ROW_HEIGHT + SPACING));
            System.out.println("===================================GHieght"+GRID_HEIGHT);
            System.out.println("===================================colCount"+colCount);
            System.out.println("===================================rowCount"+rowCount);
            // set the height of the current grid
            label.getLayoutParams().height = GRID_HEIGHT;
        }





        return convertView;
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String group = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.research_list_exp_group, null);
            groupText = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_ResearchList_ExpParentElement);
            groupImg = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_ResearchList_GroupParentImage);
            // convertView.setClickable(false);
        }
        groupText.setText(group);
        groupImg.setImageResource(groupImage.get(groupPosition));

        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    }
```

**GridAdapter:**

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    //public ArrayList<Integer> childElements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer[][] childElements;
    ImageView imgGridItem;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, Integer[][] childElements)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.childElements = childElements;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childElements.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder holder = null;
        //pos=position;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            imgGridItem = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_GridItem);
        }
        imgGridItem.setImageResource(childElements[position][0]);

        return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView imgGridItem;

    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: heyi am also having similar problem with expandablelistview .. did u found a solution for this

Comment: did u get solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Looked for hours with no solution. Here is the answer. Simply make the function getChildrenCount in the parent adapter like this:

```
@Override
public ing getChildrenCount(int groupPosition){
     return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is just pass only one child to the expandable list. So, Only one gridview will be shown in the expandable list, but with all the options you want to appear in the grid view.

so, if you have another group, with another gridview items, just add one item to that group of the expandable list, with the gridview, but in this gridview, make sure you are passing the data you want it to have. I mean, you should use the same gridview adapter, but with different data. I hope this help you.