# Double child added on expandable listview

Tags: android, duplicates, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have problem adding children ,when i add one child then on ui two child appear with same childposition..my problem is similar to these mentioned in following questions

[Child Layout is repeating many times in ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339777/child-layout-is-repeating-many-times-in-expandablelistview)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938763/double-child-entries-in-expandablelistview

But unable to find a solution .. please see my code [here](http://pastie.org/5187677)

Value for children is given using this double dimension array..

```
String[][] child = {
         mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.alerts),
         mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.alerts),
         mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.alerts),
         mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.alerts),
         mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.alerts) };
```

I used this :

```
@Override
  public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return child.length;
  }
```

but for this also child count is 5 and it shows up 10 items..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are hard-coded child position like,

```
  @Override
  public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 1;
  }
```

where as it should be `your_data_collection_size`

Also, you have hard-coded childId like,

```
  @Override
  public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
  }
```

which should be `childPosition` not `0`

If you further have any query/problem you can download and check my [`demo example from you github`](https://github.com/lalit3686/ExandableListViewDemo) and can come back to me with your query if you have any thereafter.

Comment: thanks for replying ..please see the part i have added to show how i am providing data for child

Comment: instead check my demo example and try to sort out your problem yourself. Also you haven't updated your code showed in pastebin.

Comment: thanks that sample code worked for me ..the problem was i ws not referring to current object so duplicate views were added

Comment: I knew you might be missing something with your code only, so I insisted a demo. Because it would not be feasible for me to go through your complete code and find the problem.

Comment: i have one more doubt ,,if i have multiple textviews in the child layout and need to identify unique clicks on all of them ,so by switching ids inside onclick method will do or need anyother workaround

Comment: you shouldn't ask seperate questions in the same question. Better would be go in chat rooms or post another question. If you want to discuss you can jump in Any of Android Rooms.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19079/discussion-between-shruti-and-lalit-poptani)

Comment: @Lalit Poptani Can u please provide/suggest me the same demo example for three level expandable listview. Thanks

Comment: @LalitPoptani i mentioned size and it still caused multiple child entries, so then i hardcoded the item return size to 1 and it worked :O

Comment: returning `position` from `getChildId()` and `getGroupId()` instead of `0` worked in my case. Didn't think it matters since I return `false` from `hasStableIds()`. A bit counterintuitive behavior, if you ask me.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem and turns out it's because I returned false in onGroupClick method in OnGroupClickListener. Here is a solution:

```
@Override
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // ... do stuff //
    return true; // make sure you return true.
}
```