# Child layout(GridView) is repeating count of images times in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, gridview, expandablelistview

I am facing a problem while implementing an ExpandableListView with a Grid View as a child.

Implementation is done successfully, issue arises with the count of images.
For ex: if there are 4 images in GridView, it show a grid view with more than 4 images, with a slot of 46 images. Means one slot of 4 images shown then another 4 images again shown beneath that then another and then another. Means many times the same layout is repeating in one layout. I am unable to find the source of the problem therefore I failed to resolve that.

Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.
I am not getting any error, only the images get repeated, according to the count of images.

[image]

I am getting like this, but i want images to be show only one time..irrespective of image count.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339777/child-layout-is-repeating-many-times-in-expandablelistview refer this link for code...i am doing some what same like this..only origin of images are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution..i was passing wrong count in getChildrenCountMethod

```
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {


        return 1;
    }
```

Here, i have to pass the number of children for that particular header.And my need is one child per header.

Comment: Yeah if you have seen android hive tutorial then you will also get solution.