# Android: Multi-level ExpandableListView displaying children multiple times

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I've created a 3-level (`Root, Parent, Child`) custom ExpandableListView and associated adapter thanks to some of the tutorials out there for this. I'm having trouble displaying the `Parent` level of the list, while `Root` and `Child` levels display correctly. What I'm finding is that the `Parent` level is duplicating its view N times, where N is the number of elements in the `Parent` group.

What I want:
[Three categories under Canon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n851I.png)

What I'm getting:
[The three categories under Canon are duplicated 3 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQuO0.png)

`Root` level:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, 
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

/* this list is the header of the Parent level, and I know it has the correct number of elements */
List<String> lensTypeList = listDataChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition));

/* the Parent level of the ExpandableListView */
LensSecondLevel lensSecondLevel = new LensSecondLevel(ManageLensesActivity.this);

/* all params other than lensTypeList work correctly in the later levels */
lensSecondLevel.setAdapter(new SecondLevelListViewAdapter(ManageLensesActivity.this, lensTypeList, lensMap, lensPositionIndicesMap));
```

`getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)` of `Root` level returns the correct number every time, despite how many children (`Parent`) views are created. I can't tell why `getGroupView` is getting called repeatedly for the `Parent` level.

`Parent` level:

```
@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
{
    /* _listDataHeader is the same ArrayList<String> lensTypeList from above */
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}
```

Aren't you supposed to pass an `ArrayList<String>` as the header for the 2nd level of the ExpandableListView? I can only achieve the desired result if I pass the 2nd level a single `String` as the header, but this breaks my logic for finding the `Child` level views, as `groupPosition` is always `0` since `_listDataHeader.size() == 1`

Thanks in advance for any help/advice. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35208411/5004391

I don't really understand why but I had to hardcode `getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)` for the `Root` level to return `1`, as opposed to the actual number of children. In my app's other `ExpandableListView`s I always return the number of children and it works as expected.